# Why Boostrap 4 dropright selected menu is showing like browser default button in Chrome ? Firefox have no issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

The problem arose is specific to Chrome. The dropright selected menu is showing like browser default button in Chrome whereas it appears as it should be in Firefox i.e. white in the back

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/BulRA.jpg

The Bootstrap version used is 4.3 . I have tried setting  {
border:none !important; outline:none !important; background: transparent !important; box-shadow: none !important; white-space: nowrap;} at .dropright:hover > a .

/*---------- drop down primary ------*/

```
    .navbar-nav li:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    nav li .dropdown-menu  > li > a:hover   {
        color: black !important;
        border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 0);
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    nav li .dropdown-menu > li > a:active   {
        color: black !important;
        border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 0);

    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1000;
        float: right;
        min-width: 160px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        margin: 2px 0 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3); /* here */
        -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
        background-clip: padding-box;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
        box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    }
    .dropdown-menu  li> a{
        color: white !important;
    }
    /* -----level1------ */
    .dropright:hover > .dropdown-menu{
        display: block;


    }
    .dropright:hover > a{
        color: black !important;

    }

    .dropright:hover > .dropdown-menu  > a{
        color: white !important;
    }
    .dropright:hover > .dropdown-menu  > a:hover{
        color: black !important;
        border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(39, 174, 96, 0);
      }
```

and the html is

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a
                                class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                                href="#"
                                id="navbarDropdown"
                                role="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown"
                                aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded="false"
                        >
                            WHO WE ARE
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About Us</a> </li>
                            <li class="dropdown-item dropright">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle"
                                   type="button"
                                   id="reachwellStory"
                                   data-toggle="dropdown"
                                   aria-haspopup="true"
                                   aria-expanded="false">The Reachwell Story
                                </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu " aria-labelledby="reachwellStory" >
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mission Statement</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Vision Statement</a>
                                    </div>
                            </li>

                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Leadership</a> </li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Strength</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `type=button` from the dropright menu

This should be

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle"
  type="button"
  id="reachwellStory"
  data-toggle="dropdown"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  aria-expanded="false">The Reachwell Story
</a>
```

changed to

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle"
  id="reachwellStory"
  data-toggle="dropdown"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  aria-expanded="false">The Reachwell Story
</a>
```

Comment: Though this worked by removing button. What alternative solutions are possible by not removing the type as a button?

Comment: I think you dont have to add the `type=button` to the `<a>` tag since the `<a>` tag defines a hyperlink